# How to chat and call automatically in MS Teams?

Tags: automation, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I'm working on a solution to build a system that automatically alerts users on Microsoft Teams. The order of execution will be:

1. Automatically scan alarm logs
2. Sort and send MS Teams messages to personnel for corresponding processing
3. If the processing staff does not receive the message, make a call on MS Teams to read the pre-recorded voice record.
   I used python to automatically get the warning list, to send this alert list to the handler, I have tried MS Teams REST API but it only supports sending messages to Channel. How do I automatically chat and voice calls to an MS Teams user? Can chatbot help me with this problem? I see there are many types of bots that can be added to the conversation:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think a chatbot is definitely the best way to deal with this. Essentially, you're wanting the bot to message a user on demand, which is something called "Proactive Messaging". You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-proactive-messaging) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet). There are a few things you need to know about this, but in a nutshell you need a way to specifically identify the user for sending the message, which you can get when the user first installs your bot (mostly you need "ServiceUrl" and "ConversationId").

With regards to knowing if the user has read the message, you might want to send an "adaptive card" with a button for the user to acknowledge that they've read the message, and if you don't get a callback within some time frame, start the voice call.